# Doctrine nestedset delete

Tags: php, doctrine, hierarchical-trees

I have some models witch are using Doctrine nestedset feature.
I want to add delete functionaly of elements from tree since that is required in my application. I was trying with snippets from documentation but I am getting a very strange error with that code.

YAML is here: http://pastie.org/820978

And I am trying with this code in my Menu class witch extends generated abstract class BaseMenu and BaseMenu extends Doctrine_Record :)

Anyway my code:

```
 public function getMenuItem($id)
 {
     return Doctrine::getTable('Menu')->find($id);
 }

 public function delete($id)
 {
     $item = $this->getMenuItem($id);

     //echo get_class($item); will return Menu so object exists !?

     $item->getNode()->delete();
 }
```

And I get this an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   getNode() on a non-object

And I just noticed that get_class($item) is trowing a warring (so that probabbly is reason for this strange behavior):

> Warning: get_class() expects parameter
>   1 to be object, boolean given in...

However I need a solution for this and all hints are welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getNode() returns a Doctrine_Node, not a Doctrine_Record.

A Doctrine_Record can be deleted, but a Doctrine_Node cannot be deleted -- because it is not persistent anyway.

The correct logic would simply be:

```
$item = $this->getMenuItem($id)->delete();
```

Also, don't name a method in your model 'delete'!! This will override Doctrine_Record's delete() method, which will drive you crazy trying to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't like using Doctrine::getTable("table_name") because it doesn't make the code very dry.  If for some reason "table_name" ever changes, you'll have to change it in alot of places.

I used Doctrine in Zend Framework apps, so my typical pattern of use involves instantiating a protected instance of every model in my module.

Using that pattern, I would just do this in my controller

```
$this->_Menu
     ->getTable()
     ->find($id)
     ->getNode()
     ->delete();
```

If you really want to keep your functions similar, I would use something like this

```
 public function getMenuItem($id)
 {
     if (empty($id))
     {
         throw new Exception ("A parameter of id is required to retrieve a menu item".);
     }
     return $this->getTable()->find($id);
 }

 public function delete($id)
 {
     $item = $this->getMenuItem($id);

     if ($item instanceof Doctrine_Record == false)
     {
          throw new Exception("Item is not a valid Menu Record.");
     }

     $item->getNode()->delete();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, for the coding hints but this doesn't solving my problem since I am getting the exception Item is not a valid Menu Record.
Do you have any idea how to solve it and why it isn't a Doctrine_Record at all ?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is in your question: $item is not object (i guess it's value is false, but you can use var_dump($item)), because there is no row with such id in DB (also I guess your $id is null)

> > Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, boolean given in...
> >
> > Fatal error: Call to a member function getNode() on a non-object

Comment: Dude, did u read my question!? I can access to all attributes of $item. Also get_class($item) returns Menu which yeap is confusing but Menu is class and it looks like an object :P And for sure id is not null since I am just testing the app it's not on some live website or something.

Comment: So, how can u explain this:
    Fatal error: Call to a member function getNode() on a non-object

Comment: To be honest I can't explain it, and that is confusing since I don't know where the error is. I don't get it how I am able to access to object attributes like $menu->title with this code. Do u have some snippet with nested set tree and delete function since I can't get this to work ?

Comment: Provided code is correct. I can only recommend you to ensure that your environment set to
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
and check output for all errors.